# Building Eventhub connection string with KeyVault secret

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am trying to create an Azure Function App which is an `EventHub Trigger`. The thing is that to connect to Azure Eventhub, **I don't have the full connection string**. Instead I have the Eventhub SAS token stored as `secret` in a Key Vault.

I would like to know if in the `App Settings` section there is a way to build the connection string by passing that token that I get from the key vault.

I have a variable `KEYVAULT_SAS_SECRET` whose value I want to use in another variable within the App Setting.

[image]

Would it be possible to reference the `KEYVAULT_SAS_SECRET` variable to construct the connection string that is stored in a second variable?

Something like this:

`Endpoint=sb://some-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=policy;SharedAccessKey=[KEYVAULT_SAS_SECRET];EntityPath=eventhub-topic`.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to reference Azure Function `App Settings` variable in another `App Settings` variables.

In your particular case you have to construct EventHub connection string from two `App Settings` variables directly in your code

Comment: Thanks Andriy, And how could I do it ? I ask this because the Azure function of type `Eventhub Trigger` uses a `JSON` from which the connection string is passed. In the python code of the `__init__.py` it does not reference that connection string anywhere. Thanks again!

Comment: So your Function is triggered by EventHub and you want to connect to the same EventHub from Azure Function using Python?

Comment: Yes, that's it :)

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot consume Eventhub connection string from Eventhub Trigger.
You have to create additional Function App Settings variable with EventHub connection string, read both App Settings variable(Connection string + Secret) in Python and make string concatenation